getBodyParam('email') is empty on live server
Trying to debug a form issue which is only happening on a live server (it works on our local environments).
The form makes a fetch request (using Javascript) to a route in routes.php which goes to a controller. I can see the data sent to the controller has the email address in the email field, but when it comes to the controller the field is empty.
I'm using:
$request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
$emailAddress = $request->getBodyParam('email');

$emailAddress is always empty on the live/staging/dev server.
The main difference between our local environments (we're using a mix of Mac, Windows, Herd, and DDEV) is that the servers are running REDDIS.
I've found similar issues with Craft 3 on here, but we're using Craft 5.1.2.

Discovered there was an NGINX config that was adding trailing slashes to URLs. Posting to the URL /api/controller-action was getting changed to /api/controller-action/ and emptying the POST data.
